# Bad graphics and unfinished boot from live CD, DVDs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, dvd, livecd

i3-9100F, Nvidia RTX 2060 Super

I cannot seem to get live CD/DVDs to boot. I tried:

esSET sysRescue (2022-07-18 download) boot stop screenshot:

[image: esSET sysRescue (2022-07-18 download) boot stop screenshot]

Kaspersky Rescue Disc v18.0.11.0 boot stop screenshot:

[image]

Ubuntu v18.04.6 boot stop screenshot:

[image: Ubuntu v18.04.6 boot stop screenshot]

The only one I found that does work is Ubuntu 16.04. Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: For Linux live you need either the "safe graphics" option when available (Ubuntu and derivatives) or add `nomodeset` as boot parameter. The "culprit" is your graphics in every situation. Ubuntu 20.04 or 22.04 should work in standard "Try Ubuntu".